# Vue.js img src concatenate variable and text

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to concatenate Vue.js variable with image URL.

What I computed:

```
imgPreUrl : function() {
    if (androidBuild) return "android_asset/www/";
    else return "";
}
```

If I build for android:

```
<img src="/android_asset/www/img/logo.png">
```

Else

```
<img src="img/logo.png">
```

How can I concatenate the computed variable with the URL?

I tried it:

```
<img src="{{imgPreUrl}}img/logo.png">
```

Answer (score 298, accepted):

You can't use curlies (moustache tags) in attributes. Use the following to concat data:

```
<img v-bind:src="imgPreUrl + 'img/logo.png'">
```

Or the short version:

```
<img :src="imgPreUrl + 'img/logo.png'">
```

Read more on dynamic attributes in the [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Attributes).

Comment: "But Vue.js actually supports the full power of JavaScript expressions inside all data bindings": https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Using-JavaScript-Expressions

Answer (score 58):

In another case I'm able to use template literal ES6 with backticks,
so for yours could be set as:

```
<img v-bind:src="`${imgPreUrl()}img/logo.png`">
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it seems that webpack runs before the bindings are processed because my url is outputted to the browser as "@./assets/syndicate_images/34.jpg"

Comment: `imgPreUrl` is a variable, not a function.

Answer (score 15):

just try

```html
<img :src="require(`${imgPreUrl}img/logo.png`)">
```

Comment: quick and easy, ty

Comment: This is the correct way, as stated in the documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/assets#images

Answer (score 7):

Following both method is valid.

#### Method 1

Concatenate with `+` sign and wrap string with single/double quotation.

```
<img :src="imgPreUrl() + 'img/logo.png'">
```

#### Method 2

Wrap with backtick `` ` `` and wrap variables with `${variable}`. As `imgPreUrl` is a method so,

```
<img :src="`${imgPreUrl()}img/logo.png`">
```

Answer (score 5):

if you handel this from dataBase try :

```
<img :src="baseUrl + 'path/path' + obj.key +'.png'">
```

Answer (score 2):

If it helps, I am using the following to get a gravatar image:

```
<img
        :src="`https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/${this.gravatarHash(email)}?s=${size}&d=${this.defaultAvatar(email)}`"
        class="rounded-circle"
        :width="size"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, it said Module did not found and not worked.
Finally, I found this solution and worked.

```
<img v-bind:src="require('@' + baseUrl + 'path/path' + obj.key +'.png')"/>
```

Needed to add '@' at the beginning of the local path.

Comment: Nice~
Thank you : )