# the result vue.js to an <a href>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, qr-code

I'm using scan QR code from web camera. instascan

In index.html call function app.js(instascan/docs/..) But I can't use result value in tag {{scan.content}} to link to it.

```html
 <ul id="resultQR" v-for="scan in scans" :key="scan.date" :title="scan.content">
  {{ scan.content }}
</ul>
```

It must be

```html
<a href="{{ scan.content }}">{{ scan.content }}</a>
```

Comment: Try it: `<a :href="scan.content">{{ scan.content }}</a>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.js img src concatenate variable and text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255291/vue-js-img-src-concatenate-variable-and-text)