# v-model concatenate a string with a var?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've read answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255291/vue-js-img-src-concatenate-variable-and-text), but I can't get my template to compile.

I need to concatenate a string with a variable in `v-model` to bind to an array inside an object:

```
<li v-for="name in names">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="'checked.'+name">
    ....
```

I just get a compile error though.

Also when I do this:

```
:data-test="'checked.'+name"
```

It compiles fine, so it's something with *v-model*.

The compile error is:

> Syntax Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:1161)

Comment: can you share the compile error that shows up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case a slightly different perspective helps: Whether you use it in a `v-model` or `:data-test` directive

```
'checked.'+name
```

results in a string. Although it probably isn't what one would normally want to do, that is syntactically legal for an arbitrary `v-bind` (e.g. `:data-test`). That is not, however, syntactically legal for a `v-model`. As other have pointed out, `v-model` attempts to assign a value on `"change"` events. It would be equivalent, for example, to

```
'checked.foo' = true;
```

when what I think you want is

```
checked.foo = true;
```

It's hard to say for sure without seeing more of your code, but it may be the case that

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="checked[name]">
```

is sufficient for you.

Answer (score 1):

The `v-model="name"` helps you do two things.

1. `:value="name"`
2. `@input="name = $event`

However, in your case, you're doing `v-model="'checked.'+name"`, which means:

1. `:value="'checked.'+name" // Which is perfectly fine`
2. `@input="'checked.'+name = $event" // This would cause an error.`

Documentation can be found [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter).

Below is some solution of mine: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qxtuezmj/)

```
  computed: {
    checkedName: {
      // getter
      get: function () {
        return `${this.prefix}${this.name}`;
      },
      // setter
      set: function (newValue) {
        this.name = newValue.replace(this.prefix, '');
      }
    }
  },
```

then

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="checkedName">
```

Comment: This does not work. Compile error `SyntaxError: Assigning to rvalue`

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer, but I'm afraid the binding still does not work. `return checked.${this.name}`;` how does it know the name if nothiing is passed to the setter `set: function (newValue)` from `v-model="checkedName"`?

Comment: `set:` is triggered when you do `checkedName = $event`, the `newValue` is `$event`. Check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qxtuezmj/)

Comment: Example not correct as it's not in a loop or even a checkbox.

Comment: I have updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qxtuezmj/2/), but I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve. What value you want to store in the `names`?

Comment: Why are you putting string into value of a checkbox? Shouldn't it be `boolean`?  Do you have a `object` called `checked` and you want to access its attribute using `name`? if `names[0] = 'asd'`, you want to access `checked.asd`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

`v-model` is used for two-way data binding and is a syntactic sugar for `:checked="myField"` + `@change="evt => myField = evt.target.checked` in the case of a checkbox.

As you can see, `myField` must be a valid left-hand side expression in JS, this is by the way one [of the rules](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/master/docs/rules/valid-v-model.md) precised by Vue to have a valid `v-model`:

> The directive does not have the attribute value which is valid as LHS. E.g. `<input v-model="foo() + bar()">`

And that is exactly why your template doesn't compile. Vue can understand how to bind the data in one way because it can assign `'checked.'+name` to a variable, but it can't assign a variable to `'checked.'+name` - that is not a valid left-hand sign expression.

Comment: But when I manually set the v-model to do what I want, it works fine. I'm just trying to concat a string and var name.

Comment: That's exactly what I say. Vue can concat easily. It cannot deconcat. One way of the required two-way databinding is not possible.

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you are saying. `v-model="checked.myname"` works, so why cant we just concat this value from a var?

Comment: we can *concat* we can't do the reverse. By two-way-binding to `'checked.'myname`, Vue won't be able to know which variable to update when the input value gets updated because the object reference is lost during the concatenation. Thus the error.

Comment: The object reference will not be lost during the concatenation, the concatenation creates the reference. For example, the concatenation produces `v-model="checked.myname"` which references an item in data.

Comment: Apologies, I was wrong on the object reference losing. I answered too hastily. I edited my answer so as to include an update with better explanation and a link to the docs explaining why your template won't compile. Is that better now?