# How can I bind a variable to an image source string?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to generate some v-chip objects with variable names and images. The source string of the image depends on the name. When I bind the name to the source string the image doesn't load. I already read a similar question with a solution ([Vue.js img src concatenate variable and text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255291/vue-js-img-src-concatenate-variable-and-text)) but it just doesn't work for me.

I tried two different ways as you can see in the code. One with binding a props and one with a computed function. Both not working.

```
<template>    
<div>
    <v-chip v-model="perso">
        <v-avatar>
          <img :src="'../assets/' + perso_name + '.png'"> <!--Doesn't work-->
        </v-avatar>
        {{perso_name}}
    </v-chip>   
    <v-chip v-model="perso">
        <v-avatar>
          <img :src="'../assets/' + foo + '.png'"> <!--Doesn't work-->
        </v-avatar>
        {{perso_name}}
    </v-chip>
    <v-chip v-model="perso">
        <v-avatar>
          <img src="../assets/Jon.png"> <!--This works-->
        </v-avatar>
        {{perso_name}}
    </v-chip>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
      return { perso: true }
  },
  name: 'Personal',
  props: ['perso_name'],
  computed: {
    foo: function() {
      return this.perso_name;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I don't get an error but the image isn't loading. It just shows the broken file icon.

Comment: Surround the image source with `require()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your question you didn't show your `rendered img src` of your broken file icon.So i can only speculate the problem is the file path in your server is incorrect.

The `src` attr is very special,some packing tool(like `webpack`) use this attr to locate your img,and transform/repalce it with the right path when you packing your project.

In your case,**you bind the src attr with `vue binding`,and the path looks like a `relative path from the img file to your .vue file`.** It's easy to go wrong because the browser load the img from the `root path` of your website.

i suggest you trying like this:

- use webpack import to save your packaged img path to a dictionary

```
<script>

var urlDic ={};
urlDic.Jon = require('../assets/Jon.jpg')；
urlDic.Mike = require('../assets/Mike.jpg')；

export default {
  data () {
      return { 
         urls: urlDic //save the dic to your data
       }
  },
  name: 'Personal',
  props: ['perso_name']
}
</script>
```

- the bind the img src to the `preloaded` img paths

```
     <v-chip v-model="perso">
        <v-avatar>
          <img :src="urls[perso_name]"> <!--it will work-->
        </v-avatar>
        {{perso_name}}
    </v-chip>
```

Comment: Ok, I'm new to webdevelopment. Had to research about webpack first. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use template strings. Surround the attribute value with '``' and the variable with `${}`

```
<img :src="`../assets/${perso_name}.png`">
```